# Java program with two or more exceptions caused by similar values

Tags: java, testing, faults

I am working on project where I am trying to find programs which give any exception but because of close values. Let me explain by an example. I will highly appreciate any help and support. In the following program first fault is generated when x == 100 and second when x == 98. Cheers.

```
public class Fault {

    public void faulty(int x, int y) {

        int z;
        y = 20;
        int a [] = new int[10];

        if (x == 100)
        {
            a[11] = 22;
        }

        if ( x == 98)
            z= ( x + y )/0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear. If this is a request for "such programs" then I'm not sure this is the place for that.

Comment: What do you want to know? Do you want to do static code analysis which reveals possible error paths in your application and discover similar error paths depending on variable state?

Comment: @Asbat: You must update your question and provide more details. No one here does understand your problem...

Comment: You mean like `Object o = null; if (x == 96) o.toString();`?

Answer (score 3):

The second is obvious:

```
if ( x == 98)
    z= ( x + y )/0;
```

Only [Jon Skeet can divide by zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9138#9138).

Comment: +1 "Only Jon Skeet can divide by zero." Classic :)

Comment: I know the faults in the above programs but I want to write few more examples where the exceptions are caused by close range values for other types like byte, char, long, String etc.